# Mocking pymongo in Flask

Tags: python, mocking, flask, pymongo

I've got little problem with testing my Flask app. My view looks like this:

```
def prelogin():
    email = request.args.get('email')
    if not email:
        return '', 204
    user = User.query.filter({'email': email}).first()
    if not user:
        return '', 204
    address = current_app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_URL']
    try:
        mongo_photo = pymongo.db.photos.find_one(user.photo)
        photo = address + mongo_photo['file']
    except (KeyError, AttributeError):
        photo = None
    return jsonify({
        'email': email,
        'fullname': user.fullname,
        'photo': photo
    })
```

and my test function like this:

```
@patch('arounded.userv2.views.User')
@patch('arounded.userv2.views.pymongo')
def test_valid_prelogin(self, mock_user, mock_pymongo):
    user_config = {
        'filter.return_value.first.return_value.fullname': 'Someone'
    }
    mock_user.query.configure_mock(**user_config)
    mock_pymongo.db.photos.find_one.return_value = {'file': 'no-photo.png'}
    response = self.client.get(
        '/api/v2/users/prelogin?email=someone@example.com')
    self.assert_status(response, 200)
```

If I try to print mock objects in test function, they return correct values. Yet in view I'm still getting:

```
arounded/userv2/views.py line 40 in prelogin
  'photo': photo
/home/sputnikus/.virtualenvs/arounded_site2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_jsonpify.py line 60 in jsonpify
  indent=None if request.is_xhr else 2)),
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py line 250 in dumps
  sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py line 209 in encode
  chunks = list(chunks)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py line 434 in _iterencode
  for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py line 408 in _iterencode_dict
  for chunk in chunks:
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py line 442 in _iterencode
  o = _default(o)
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py line 184 in default
  raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <MagicMock name='pymongo.db.photos.find_one().__getitem__().__radd__()' id='67038032'> is not JSON serializable
```

`mongo_photo` variable is returned as `<MagicMock name='pymongo.db.photos.find_one()' id='59485392'>`.

Do I use mock bad way, patching on wrong place?

Comment: Why are we seeing `''.join` in your exception traceback, but not in the body of the prelogin() function you pasted above? Is the traceback from the same version of the code as the one you're showing?

Note also that your "except AttributeError" won't work, I think you want "except KeyError".

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis I apologize, mixed old exception with new code. Both are up to date now, problem persists. Thank you for correction.

Comment: I think your `mock_user` and `mock_pymongo` arguments are in wrong order; the outermost @patch (first/furthest away from the method) is the last method argument.

Comment: @TommiKomulainen That looks like problem. Thank you very much. Can you write a proper answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `mock_user` and `mock_pymongo` arguments are in wrong order; the outermost @patch (first/furthest away from the method) is the last method argument. It should be

```
@patch('arounded.userv2.views.User')
@patch('arounded.userv2.views.pymongo')
def test_valid_prelogin(self, mock_pymongo, mock_user):
```